Unknown extension .ts for wdio.web.chrome.conf.ts
I have problem with Jenkins job after moving agent to K8S.
I'm getting this error:
2024-08-26T14:59:08.150Z ERROR @wdio/config:ConfigParser: Failed loading configuration file: file:///home/jenkins/agent/workspace/{PATH}/src/aim/config/wdio.web.chrome.conf.ts: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/{PATH}/src/aim/config/wdio.web.chrome.conf.ts
11:59:09  TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/{PATH}/src/aim/config/wdio.web.chrome.conf.ts
11:59:09      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
11:59:09      at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:80:11)
11:59:09      at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:122:38)
11:59:09      at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:81:20)
11:59:09      at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
11:59:09      at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:602:26)
11:59:09      at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:458:22)
11:59:09      at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:63:26)
11:59:09      at #createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:477:17)
11:59:09      at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:435:34) {
11:59:09    code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
11:59:09  }

My build agent configuration is based on node:18.9.0 and looks like that:
FROM {ARTIFACTORY}:443/docker/library/node:18.9.0

ENV NODE_OPTIONS = '--openssl-legacy-provider'

RUN npm config set registry https://{ARTIFACTORY}/artifactory/api/npm/npm -g

# Install sonar-scanner tool
RUN npm install sonar-scanner -g

# Install npm-cli-login tool
RUN npm install npm-cli-login -g

# Install chromedriver tool
RUN npm install chromedriver -g

# Install cypress
RUN npm install cypress@13.6.3 -g
RUN cypress install

# Install typescript
RUN npm install typescript@5.2.2 -g

# Install apt dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt install -y \
  packages...

RUN wget -qO - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/googlechrome-linux-keyring.gpg \
    && echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/googlechrome-linux-keyring.gpg] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
    && apt update -y \
    && apt install -y google-chrome-stable 

# Set default user to 'node'
USER node

Later on, npm run aim:chrome is run in pipeline which point to that: "aim:chrome": "wdio src/aim/config/wdio.web.chrome.conf.ts"
Im trying to understand, if this is some problem with our build environment, but I don't have huge experience with these libraries. I tried to use different version of node, use public artifactory, ts-node is in 10.9.2 version. Could somebody give my any hints that what else should I check?
